Join timestamps between 2 datasets while maintaining time difference
I have the following 2 datasets:

This one is very reliable at telling me if an event happened, but it's timestamp is only good to within a few seconds (let's assume 2 seconds):
coarse = {
    "name": ["a", "a", "b", "c", "a"],
    "timestamp": [100, 103, 195, 220, 221],
}
coarse_df = pl.DataFrame(coarse)
"""
┌──────┬───────────┐
│ name ┆ timestamp │
│ ---  ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ i64       │
╞══════╪═══════════╡
│ a    ┆ 100       │
│ a    ┆ 103       │
│ b    ┆ 195       │
│ c    ┆ 220       │
│ a    ┆ 221       │
└──────┴───────────┘
"""




This one has a very accurate timing, but it has some noise/false positives (note that t=0 is different for both datasets, there is an arbitrary offset):
fine = {
    "name": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "b", "a"],
    "time": [0.05, 10.05, 12.51, 51.12, 106.0, 128.01, 130.0, 132.9],
}
fine_df = pl.DataFrame(fine)
"""
┌──────┬────────┐
│ name ┆ time   │
│ ---  ┆ ---    │
│ str  ┆ f64    │
╞══════╪════════╡
│ a    ┆ 0.05   │
│ a    ┆ 10.05  │
│ a    ┆ 12.51  │
│ a    ┆ 51.12  │
│ b    ┆ 106.0  │
│ c    ┆ 128.01 │
│ b    ┆ 130.0  │
│ a    ┆ 132.9  │
└──────┴────────┘
"""




I am trying to somehow join these data sets to obtain something like the following. Essentially getting the timestamps from the second dataset, and using the time differences in the first dataset to filter out the false-positives.
"""
┌──────┬────────┐
│ name ┆ time   │
│ ---  ┆ ---    │
│ str  ┆ f64    │
╞══════╪════════╡
│ a    ┆ 10.05  │
│ a    ┆ 12.51  │
│ b    ┆ 106.0  │
│ c    ┆ 128.01 │
│ a    ┆ 132.9  │
└──────┴────────┘
"""

EDIT
What I am currently doing to identify false positive (in words, because this is an ugly nested for loop):
Given that the offset between both datasets is arbitrary, assume that the first "a" event is the real one:
Now coarse looks like shifting time by 100:
┌──────┬───────────┐
│ name ┆ timestamp │
│ ---  ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ i64       │
╞══════╪═══════════╡
│ a    ┆ 0         │  -> Good, there is a timestamp in `fine` within 2s
│ a    ┆ 3         │  -> Bad, no timestamp in `fine` matches
│ b    ┆ 95        │  -> Bad, ditto
│ c    ┆ 120       │  -> Bad, ditto
│ a    ┆ 121       │  -> Bad, ditto
└──────┴───────────┘

Ok, I didn't find all hits, then the second "a" must be the real one (shifting  by 90 seconds instead):
┌──────┬───────────┐
│ name ┆ timestamp │
│ ---  ┆ ---       │
│ str  ┆ i64       │
╞══════╪═══════════╡
│ a    ┆ 10        │  -> Good, it matches 10.05
│ a    ┆ 13        │  -> Good, it matches 12.51
│ b    ┆ 105       │  -> Good, it matches 106.0
│ c    ┆ 130       │  -> Good, it matches 128.01
│ a    ┆ 131       │  -> Good it matches 132.9
└──────┴───────────┘

Basically, I am sliding the second dataset through time until I find a "time pattern" that matches all events in the first dataframe into a subset of the second one.

Could you explain how exactly you’re usimg time difference to filter out false positives? How go you know that you need to skip first record for name = a and second one for name = b?

HI @roman I made an edit explaining how I use the time differences to filter out false positives. Now that I have tried of explain what I am doing in words, I am starting to think that this might be super specific, and I'll just have to stick to ugly nested loops. I'll play a bit with join_asof and strategy=nearest. Maybe there is something less ugly I can figure out with it.

So whats your question? Your sliding approach seems to work

My question is: Is there a clean way to do this with polars df transformations?

Where do the 100, 90 values come from? It may be useful if you show your current approach. You can ASOF JOIN e.g. coarse_df.with_columns(pl.col.timestamp - 90.0).join_asof(fine_df, by="name", left_on="timestamp", right_on="time", strategy="nearest")  gives your final example. But it sounds like you want to compare a set of "shift values" and then find the result with the most near matches?

The 100 is the shift needed to match to the first row in coarse to the first row in fine, then 90 is the shift needed to match it to the second row in fine, etc.
I know I'm doing a bad job at explaining this, give me a while to try and clean up a little bit what I am doing. It is currently such a mess, that it would cause more harm than good.

@jqurious Yes, what you wrote is basically what I needed. And the "set of shift values" are all shifts that would make the first event in coarse match events in fine of the same name. Feel free to add it as an answer. It is way cleaner than the mess I am doing :)

I thought the idea is to find the proper shift. For example 90 works for given example but maybe for another example you would need 92 to match it properly? Or do you know the granularity in advance?

The final table can be generated with an ASOF JOIN using the "nearest" strategy.
(coarse_df
  .with_columns(pl.col.timestamp - 90.0)  
  .join_asof(fine_df, by="name", left_on="timestamp", right_on="time", strategy="nearest")
)

shape: (5, 3)
┌──────┬───────────┬────────┐
│ name ┆ timestamp ┆ time   │
│ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---    │
│ str  ┆ f64       ┆ f64    │
╞══════╪═══════════╪════════╡
│ a    ┆ 10.0      ┆ 10.05  │
│ a    ┆ 13.0      ┆ 12.51  │
│ b    ┆ 105.0     ┆ 106.0  │
│ c    ┆ 130.0     ┆ 128.01 │
│ a    ┆ 131.0     ┆ 132.9  │
└──────┴───────────┴────────┘

However, it sounds like you want to compare multiple "shift values" at once.
(
   pl.concat(
      coarse_df.with_columns(pl.col.timestamp - float(shift), shift=shift)
      for shift in range(100, -10, -10)
   )
   .sort("timestamp") # asof requires sorted data
   .join_asof(fine_df, by="name", left_on="timestamp", right_on="time", strategy="nearest")
   .filter((pl.col.timestamp - pl.col.time).abs() <= 2) # within threshold
)

shape: (8, 4)
┌──────┬───────────┬───────┬────────┐
│ name ┆ timestamp ┆ shift ┆ time   │
│ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ str  ┆ f64       ┆ i32   ┆ f64    │
╞══════╪═══════════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ a    ┆ 0.0       ┆ 100   ┆ 0.05   │
│ a    ┆ 10.0      ┆ 90    ┆ 10.05  │
│ a    ┆ 13.0      ┆ 90    ┆ 12.51  │
│ a    ┆ 50.0      ┆ 50    ┆ 51.12  │
│ a    ┆ 53.0      ┆ 50    ┆ 51.12  │
│ b    ┆ 105.0     ┆ 90    ┆ 106.0  │
│ c    ┆ 130.0     ┆ 90    ┆ 128.01 │
│ a    ┆ 131.0     ┆ 90    ┆ 132.9  │
└──────┴───────────┴───────┴────────┘

And find the shift(s) with the most values.
   ...
   .with_columns(pl.len().over("shift"))
   .filter(pl.col.len == pl.col.len.max())
)   

shape: (5, 5)
┌──────┬───────────┬───────┬────────┬─────┐
│ name ┆ timestamp ┆ shift ┆ time   ┆ len │
│ ---  ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ --- │
│ str  ┆ f64       ┆ i32   ┆ f64    ┆ u32 │
╞══════╪═══════════╪═══════╪════════╪═════╡
│ a    ┆ 10.0      ┆ 90    ┆ 10.05  ┆ 5   │
│ a    ┆ 13.0      ┆ 90    ┆ 12.51  ┆ 5   │
│ b    ┆ 105.0     ┆ 90    ┆ 106.0  ┆ 5   │
│ c    ┆ 130.0     ┆ 90    ┆ 128.01 ┆ 5   │
│ a    ┆ 131.0     ┆ 90    ┆ 132.9  ┆ 5   │
└──────┴───────────┴───────┴────────┴─────┘


Thanks, the final table is exactly what I needed. But you are hard-coding "shifts" in steps of 10 and started by 100. The shifts should be all of those needed to match the first coarse event with all potential true fine events.
In the example above, these shifts would be: 100, 90, 87, 49, and -33. But this is now something I can figure out myself. Thanks again

If you can unaccept this answer I can delete it. You should edit the question to include this updated information to allow people to give more relevant answers.
